# What is this vinca like vine?

Tags: botany, species-identification, toxicology, ethnobiology

What is this vinca like vine? Is it poisonous? 62521 USA Illinois

[image]
[image]

Comment: From what region of the world was this photo taken? That can help to narrow down the range of possibilities.

Comment: Across the river and down the street from you @MikeTaylor

Comment: I think it must be a climbing *Euonymus*. Given its status as a horticultural weed, it's possible you'll get a more informative response on the Gardening & Landscaping SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wintercreeper, *Euonymus fortunei*

Given that you're just over in Illinois, here's the [page from our Plant Finder database](http://tinyurl.com/nkmetp5).

In regards to your second question, this [factsheet from UMich](http://climbers.lsa.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/EuonfortCELAFINAL.pdf) mentions (and gives citations) for its use as a medicine. Given that, I'd avoid eating it if I were you, but there's not mention of it being especially toxic.

Comment: Based on the MO Botanical Gardens information for this region, it seems like a good plant to try to remove to prevent further spreading.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty weedy in my garden certainly, where it tries to climb the trees as in the photo.